# How to Communicate New Features to Delivery Team

Tags: agile, scrum, teamwork, release-management

In our company we have to development teams.

The Product Team and the Delivery Team.

I am working in the Product Team and the Delivery Team is consuming the framework, libraries, and services we are delivering to them.

They use them to create their own version of the Software, driven by their customers, and end-users.

What would be the best approach to train them in new features we develop?

Should we have release notes? I guess so, but is that sufficient?

Should we have trainings right before a release?

What would be the best approach?

We are planning on releasing every 3 months, and we are working with one week Sprints, and Scrum.

Comment: Product Owner per delivery team would be useful.

Comment: We have, but how should they interact?

Comment: "should" is hard to answer since we don't know anything about the groups involved.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to discuss this with the delivery team. It probably depends on the extent of the release in question.

Does the delivery team request specific features and wait for the new release with baited breath? In that case, they'll probably want release notes and user-facing documentation.

Are you pushing out releases and they rarely take notice except when there's a problem? Release notes are probably sufficient.

Are you releasing something with a significant paradigm shift from what they're used to? You probably want to let them know in advance and maybe organize training on top of the great user-facing docs you're writing.